# elastix API for communicating with django web application

Tags: django, voip, asterisk, elastix

I have VOIP server running Elastix, and web application in Django running on different server. I want to communicate between these two server for transferring data and use them in IVR, such as getting user id and password from phone keypad and check it in Django database and then give related data to user using IVR.

Is there any framework or API to do this?
Does anyone know about VOIP server??
pleas help . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know this particular appliance, but it seems to run on [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/). The Asterisk API for this kind of stuff is called [AGI (Asterisk Gateway Interface)](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI).

> The Asterisk Gateway Interface is an interface for adding functionality to Asterisk with many different programming languages. Perl, PHP, C, Pascal, Bourne Shell - it's your choice, really.
>
> - **AGI** may control the dial plan, called in extensions.conf.
> - **Async AGI** Introduced in Asterisk 1.6, allows asynchronous AGI scripting.
> - **EAGI** gives the application the possibility to access and control the sound channel in addition to interaction with the dial plan.
> - **FastAGI** can be used to do the processing on a remote machine via a network connection.
> - **DeadAGI** gives access to a dead channel, after hangup. Deprecated since Asterisk 1.6

source: http://www.voip-info.org

Answer (score 1):

AJAM is your best option:
[The Aynchronous Javascript Asterisk Manager (AJAM)](http://www.the-asterisk-book.com/unstable/manager-interface-ajam.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is **Elastix REST API** solution that written in `PHP` with no dependencies required.
[elastix-api](https://github.com/101t/elastix-api) also you could check a [document](https://github.com/101t/elastix-api/wiki/Elastix-API-Document) on how to install it beside Elastix server, contains important functions such as:

1. Live call
2. CDR Report
3. Download call records *.wav file

and many things.